# Wordpress: Relationship field inside a block element

Tags: php, wordpress, block, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to create a custom block using ACF. I have followed their details here: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/blocks/

I am having an issue displaying the content from my relationship field though...

- I have setup the custom post type
- I have created the ACF custom field which links to the block
- I have added content to my custom posts.

It displays 2 posts.. but none of the data.

Attached is my code and reviewing the ACF site I cannot work out what I am doing wrong. Please help.

```
<?php

/**
 * Client Slider Template.
 *
 * @param   array $block The block settings and attributes.
 * @param   string $content The block inner HTML (empty).
 * @param   bool $is_preview True during AJAX preview.
 * @param   (int|string) $post_id The post ID this block is saved to.
 */

?>

<?php
    $featured_posts = get_field('clients');
    if( $featured_posts ): ?>

        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme work-snippets">

            <?php foreach( $featured_posts as $post ): 
                setup_postdata($post); ?>

                    <div>
                        <?php 
                        $image = get_field('client_logo');
                        if( !empty( $image ) ): ?>
                            <img src="<?php echo esc_url($image['url']); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($image['alt']); ?>" />
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <p><strong><?php the_field( 'project_title' ); ?></strong></p>
                        <p><?php the_field( 'project_overview' ); ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Close Work Snippet -->

            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </div>
        <!-- Work Snippets -->

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```